# SharePoint 2013 - 1 field is missing when trying to edit a list record

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a SharePoint list that has 6 columns (see image). A whole department has been given access to the teamsite and they all have the ability to edit records on the list, except one member who is able to edit records EXCEPT one column: a single choice column (see the arrow in the above).

**What I see:**
[image: What I see]

**What they see:**
[image: What I see]

I've even tried making user a site owner, but that did not change anything. They are supposed to be able to see a checkbox and should be able to tick/untick it, but they don't see the checkbox, nor corresponding field name. It's just hidden on their screen.

I've tried removing them completely from the teamsite and re-adding them as a teamsite owner, but that did not change anything.

These are my **content type settings**:
**Content Type Settings**
[image: Content Type Settings]

The other "Choice" type columns are completely identical in configuration.

How can I fix this for the one user that can't see the checkbox in the record-editing window?

Comment: Is there any custom javascript code added on the form page? Can you please check and share the code added to form page if any?

Comment: Or create a brand new list with a selection column to check if the user still can’t see the column.

Comment: @GaneshSanap this is the code when I clicked "Edit Source" after selecting the list web part on the page: https://i.imgur.com/IQlbcli.png

Comment: @Julie_MSFT my list is already actively in use and has data in it. May I ask for your recommendation on how to approach your suggestion?